# How to tag stacks deployed by CDK Pipelines?

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

When doing a `CloudFormationCreateUpdateStackAction` in a CodePipeline (@aws-cdk/aws-codepipeline), you can pass in the tags via `templateConfiguration` property.

This will tag all resources created by the Stack deployed.

However, this stack action is abstracted when you use CDK Pipelines Library. (aws-cdk-lib.pipelines).

How do you achieve this with CDK Pipelines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the source code [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/aa19ec05835a7c71e1aa01dcd649a4d933ef1fd8/packages/%40aws-cdk/pipelines/lib/blueprint/stack-deployment.ts#L85-L114) and [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/aa19ec05835a7c71e1aa01dcd649a4d933ef1fd8/packages/%40aws-cdk/pipelines/lib/codepipeline/codepipeline.ts#L651-L681), it appears that the `pipelines.CodePipeline` construct simply applies the stack's tags to the `templateConfiguration`.

If your stacks are added in a `cdk.Stage` subclass, you can apply tags the usual way:

```js
cdk.Tags.of(stack).add('DeployContext', 'PipelineStage');
```

If your app reuses stack code in different scope contexts (i.e. a stack may or may not be in a `cdk.Stage` context), set Pipeline-only tags like this:

```js
// identify whether a stack has a pipeline stage ancestor
const stage = !cdk.App.isApp(cdk.Stage.of(myStack)) ? cdk.Stage.of(myStack) : undefined;

// add tags for pipeline deployments only
if (stage?.stageName) {
  cdk.Tags.of(myStack).add('StageName', stage?.stageName);
}
```